# Find one document in mongodb per array value

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to query the db and use an array of values in a find to get one document per value.

Is this possible to do this within one query?

For example:

Using an array of countries: `["GB", "FR", "DE"]`

Only using 1 query, instead of looping over the countries array, get one document for each value so the response of the query should look like this:

```
[
  { "_id": 0, country: "GB" },
  { "_id": 1, country: "FR" },
  { "_id": 2, country: "DE" }
]
```

I've looked through MongoDB documentation and stackoverflow and haven't found an answer relating to my question. Most queries are trying to find a value in an array.

Comment: Have you checked out [$in](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {
      country: {$in: ["GB", "FR", "DE"]}
  }},
  {$group: {
      _id: "$country",
      data: {$first: "$$ROOT"}
  }},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$data"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CDT8npn2vBt)